# Trying to access different parts of a tuple, getting: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, list, tuples, indices

I am trying to take a tuple that looks like the following:

```
('Sat Feb 29 13:32:59 +0000 2020', '1233746991752122368', 0.67, 0.293, 0.313, 0.316, 0.458, 'positive', 'joy')
```

And access the first part: `'Sat Feb 29 13:32:59 +0000 2020'`

I then want to take specific parts of this tuple and assign them to different variables as seen in my code below, however I am running to the issue `builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

```
    import calendar
def converting_timestamps(array):
    """reformat date column"""
    month_abbr = data[0][4:7]    
    month = list(calendar.month_abbr).index(month_abbr)
    year = data[0][26:30]
    date = data[0][8:11]
    time = data[0][11:20]
    return("{}-{}-{} {}".format(year, month, date, time))
```

What do I need to change within my code to fix this issue?

Entire relevant code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import log
from collections import Counter

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors


def load_metrics(filename):
    """extract data based on filename"""
    lst = ['3','4','5','6','7','15']
    with open(filename, newline='') as File:
        rows=csv.reader(File,delimiter=",")
        reader = csv.reader(File)
        data1 = []
        for row in reader:
            data1.append(row)
    test = np.array(data1)
    first = test[:, 0:2]
    scnd = test[:, 7:14]
    third = test[:, 15:]
    data = np.concatenate((first,scnd,third),axis=1)
    return data
    pass


def unstructured_to_structured(data, indexes):
    """remove header row, convert values to float unless specified, then convert to tuple"""
    
    #convert to dataframe
    dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'])

    #code to remove header
    dropped = dataframe1.drop(0, axis=0)

    #code to convert all columns to float other than those specified by index
    update = dropped.astype({'2': 'f8','3': 'f8','4': 'f8','5': 'f8','6': 'f8'})

    #code to convert every row into a tuple
    data = update.to_records(index=False)
    return data
    pass

    import calendar
def converting_timestamps(array):
    """reformat date column"""
    month_abbr = data[0][4:7]    
    month = list(calendar.month_abbr).index(month_abbr)
    year = data[0][26:30]
    date = data[0][8:11]
    time = data[0][11:20]
    return("{}-{}-{} {}".format(year, month, date, time))
```

Comment: Can you please mention the line number? where you are getting this error

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense as it is. Please use some IDE to fix basic SyntaxErrors.

Comment: My code is basically trying to take `Tue Feb 04 17:04:01 +0000 2020` and turn it into `2020-02-04 17:04:01`

Comment: It says my error is occurring on line 2 which is unusual, but the array you see mentioned in the function is calling a different function. this array is in the form of tuples and is called `data`

Comment: That's not what we asked. Things like missing variables and syntax errors should be solved *before* asking the question. Providing a piece of code that can be copy-pasted to immediately reproduce the problem makes your question much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I am using wing already. 
`data = unstructured_to_structured(load_metrics("covid_sentiment_metrics.csv"), [0, 1, 7, 8]) 
data[:]['created_at'] = converting_timestamps(data[:]['created_at'])
print(data[:]['created_at'][0].dtype)
print(month_abbr)
print(type(month_abbr))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 3, line 2
builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

This is what I am plugging in and the error it is returning

Comment: Please add the entire code so that I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: I added the entire code relevant to the question in the original question i posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    month_abbr = str(array[0][4:7]) # array[0] would be a string
    month_num = list(calendar.month_abbr).index(month_abbr)
    year = str(array[0][26:30])
    date = str(array[0][8:11])
    time = str(array[0][11:20])
```

Considering data as array, `data()` will act as a function to retrieve data using index, you need to use square brackets `[]`

Comment: @codingfailure have you tried this?

Comment: I have updated my code above, please take a look at it. I seem to be running into a new issue as I have updated my code to have `data = update.to_records(index=False)` at the end of the new function. I now realise the problem is I am struggling to turn the dataframe in the second function into a tuple. If you could please help me sort that out, that will most likely fix the issues with the third function as well. Currently, rather than being type tuple, data is type `<class 'numpy.recarray'>`